# What to do while the mezuzah is being checked?

Tags: mezuzah

We're having all our mezuzot checked.  It is going to take at least a day to get them back.

Is there anything that should be done during the evening while the apartment has no mezuzahs up?  Should we put up a "temporary" mezuzah of some sort?

Comment: I think this is a dupe

Comment: The question is part of a dupe, but there is no answer in the dup as to this particular issue.

Comment: Answer could be taken from here: http://hebrewstam.blogspot.co.il/2012/08/blog-post_4310.html

Comment: @DannySchoemann an answer there does address this question: "There is a preference to put up loaner mezuzahs in the interim, particularly if they will be down overnight. However, for most this is not an option or it becomes too burdensome. Some prefer to leave a mezuzah up while the rest are being checked. However, this is not required."